# react redirecting login page to home page

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react typescript to create a login page, I found a tutorial that ran over having to build the login page and display successfully if it was a good login (I hardcoded the login credentials). once I find that it is successful I'm having a hard time redirecting the page. How would I redirect to my home page after success login?

Here's the code:

```
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {TextField, Card, CardContent, CardActions, CardHeader, Button, Switch, colors } from '@material-ui/core';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    container: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      width: 400,
      margin: `${theme.spacing(0)} auto`
    },
    loginBtn: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
      flexGrow: 1,
      background:'#5253af'
    },
    header: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      background: '#5253af',
      color: '#c0c0c0'
    },
    card: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(10)
    }
  })
);

//state type

type State = {
  username: string
  password:  string
  isButtonDisabled: boolean
  helperText: string
  isError: boolean
};

const initialState:State = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
  isButtonDisabled: true,
  helperText: '',
  isError: false
};

type Action = { type: 'setUsername', payload: string }
  | { type: 'setPassword', payload: string }
  | { type: 'setIsButtonDisabled', payload: boolean }
  | { type: 'loginSuccess', payload: {} }
  | { type: 'loginFailed', payload: string }
  | { type: 'setIsError', payload: boolean };

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'setUsername': 
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.payload
      };
    case 'setPassword': 
      return {
        ...state,
        password: action.payload
      };
    case 'setIsButtonDisabled': 
      return {
        ...state,
        isButtonDisabled: action.payload
      };
    case 'loginSuccess': 
      alert('here');
      return {
        ...state,
        helperText: SwitchPage(),
        isError: false
      };
    case 'loginFailed': 
      return {
        ...state,
        helperText: action.payload,
        isError: true
      };
    case 'setIsError': 
      return {
        ...state,
        isError: action.payload
      };
  }
}

function SwitchPage(): string {
  return 'Successful'
}

const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.username.trim() && state.password.trim()) {
     dispatch({
       type: 'setIsButtonDisabled',
       payload: false
     });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: 'setIsButtonDisabled',
        payload: true
      });
    }
  }, [state.username, state.password]);

  function HandleLogin() {
    if (state.username === '1' && state.password === '1') {
      dispatch({
        type: 'loginSuccess',
        payload: 'Login success!'
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: 'loginFailed',
        payload: 'Incorrect username or password'
      });
    }
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      state.isButtonDisabled || HandleLogin();
    }
  };

  const handleUsernameChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> =
    (event) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'setUsername',
        payload: event.target.value
      });
    };

  const handlePasswordChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> =
    (event) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'setPassword',
        payload: event.target.value
      });
    }
  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardHeader className={classes.header} title="Login" />
        <CardContent>
          <div>
            <TextField
              error={state.isError}
              fullWidth
              id="username"
              type="email"
              label="Username"
              placeholder="Username"
              margin="normal"
              onChange={handleUsernameChange}
              onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
            />
            <TextField
              error={state.isError}
              fullWidth
              id="password"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              placeholder="Password"
              margin="normal"
              helperText={state.helperText}
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
              onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
            />
          </div>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.loginBtn}
            onClick={HandleLogin}
            disabled={state.isButtonDisabled}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a onSubmit handler on the form element to handle the submit event.

```
<form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} ... />
```

Since you are using react-router-dom. You can make use of the useHistory hook from react-router-dom and get a object from it like below. Make sure to import useHistory.

```
const history=useHistory();
```

If Any extra or validation required do it inside the `handleOnSubmit` function in DOM and at the end. Make use of push function from the history object which you got from react-router-dom;

```
const submitForm = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // Preventing the page from reloading
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do something 
    alert(term);
  
    ....

    history.push(..specify_route_here..) 

}
```